# How can I create Drawable (or XmlResourceParser object) from XML source code provided as a string?

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable, xmlresourceparser

How can I create `Drawable` from XML source code **provided as a string**?

I found the following method:

```
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromXml();
```

But it requires to provide `XmlResourceParser` - and I still don't see a way to create it from XML source code.

Sample of the XML source code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:gravity="right"
            />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just think of this, maybe not exactly syntactically correct but I believe this is something you want.

```
public Drawable xmlStringToDrawable(String yourString){
     XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
     parser.setInput(new StringReader(yourString));
     return Drawable.createFromXml(getResources(),parser)
}
```

Comment: Btw, as @pskink said, if you want to dynamically change a drawable that is set to some view. You should not parse a xml, since xml parsing is a very slow process. What you should do is to programmatically set drawable to a view. If you want to change attributes like gravity of a view, you can also change the **layoutParams** of the view instead.

Comment: I'm getting `error: unreported exception XmlPullParserException; must be caught or declared to be thrown` with this code.

Comment: How can I change `layoutParams` of the background??? It's just `Drawable` and it doesn't have any `layoutParams`.

Comment: I have not use this api from the SDK ever, but you can try wrap it with a try catch block if it said so.

Comment: May I ask when will your drawable be used ? Will it eventually be set to a View? If so, you should change the layout params of the view. I think you are mixing up some of the concepts here. Drawable does not contain any information about how it should be placed in the view, so if you need to adjust it's position, you should explicitly pass information and set it programmatically.

Comment: The XML code from the question works fine. I can't change layout (it's private API) - I can only set background of already existing view.

Answer (score 0):

**FYI**

[**`createFromXml()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#createFromXml(android.content.res.Resources,%20org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme))

> Create a drawable from an **XML document** using an optional Resources.Theme.

Try this

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

        Drawable testDrawable;

        Resources res = getResources();
        try {
            testDrawable = Drawable.createFromXml(res, res.getXml(R.xml.test));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Error", "Exception creating drawable from XML");
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: I want to create it from XML code - not from XML file.

Comment: @Dmitry **FYI** **[createFromXml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#createFromXml(android.content.res.Resources,%20org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme))**  `Create a drawable from an XML document using an optional Resources.Theme`

Comment: @Dmitry get Your drawable like this `drawable= ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.test);`

Comment: [Convert base64 string to image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42295088/5712938)

Comment: @pskink I don't feel, what is he really want to achieve `LayerDrawable shape = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.drawable_item);`, and `someView.setBackgroundDrawable(shape);`. `layer-list` is a drawable, which he can use like a normal drawable image. But in a title is something about image in string form.

Comment: Please remove this answer and comments because they have nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question. But it solved my problem. Thanks everyone for the help:

```
        Drawable icon = resources.getDrawable(resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.arrayName).getResourceId(index, 0), context.getTheme());
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) icon;
        bitmapDrawable.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

I generate only `index` on run-time in this approach.